# Parsing binary structures into a struct in a single iteration of the data

Tags: rust

I am writing a library in rust to deserialize LTV (length type value) data into a struct in rust. An binary ltv object like

```
L  T  V  L  T    V
02 01 0A 03 02 00 0B
```

is currently being implemented something like this:

```
struct LTVObject{
    pub field_1: u8,
    pub field_2: u16,
}
impl LTVObject {
    pub fn parse(r: &LtvReader) -> LTVResult<Self>{
        Ok(LTVObject {
            field_1: r.read_field(1)?,
            field_2: r.read_field(2)?,
        })
    }
}
```

The problem with this implementation is every call to `read_field` is looping through the LTV structure to find the field. For large objects, this is very slow. What I want to do is make it so that ltv data only needs to be iterated once. My thinking is to change the parsing to:

```
pub fn parse(r: &LtvReader) -> LTVResult<Self>{
    let mut inst = Self{ ... };
    for field in r.get_fields(){
        match field.id {
            1 => inst.field_1 = field.get_value()?,
            2 => inst.field_2 = field.get_value()?,
       }
    }
    Ok(inst)
}
```

However there are a few design problems im unsure how to resolve

1. Returning an error if one of the fields does not exist in the LTV
2. Creating the `inst` variable without the `Default` trait

In the actual library, the `parse` function is generated from a macro so I would like to avoid having the constraint that `Default` needs to be implemented on the field types.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the values into `Option`s and then check that you have them all. Something like this:

```
pub fn parse(r: &LtvReader) -> LTVResult<Self> {
    let mut field_1 = None;
    let mut field_2 = None;

    for field in r.get_fields(){
        match field.id {
            1 => field_1 = Some(field.get_value()?),
            2 => field_2 = Some(field.get_value()?),
       }
    }
    Ok(LTVObject {
        field_1: field_1.ok_or(Error::MissingField)?,
        field_2: field_2.ok_or(Error::MissingField)?,
    })
}
```

Comment: I was about to write somthing like your updated version using a builder struct - but I think this is just as nice. Two things that can be added relatively trivially. 1. `_ => return Err(...)`. 2. checking that the value is only set once.

Comment: Using local Option<T> was also an idea I was thinking about, but I thought it might get a bit messy when the struct has an optional field. It would work if I was implementing the parsing myself, but the goal is to be generated from a macro.

Comment: If the field is optional then the macro can handle that field differently, so it isn't an error.

Comment: It's hard to give a better suggestion without seeing your macro, but it must know the types. If type 3 is optional then `field_3` would get initialized as `Some(None)` instead of `None`.

Comment: The macro currently handles all the fields exactly the same, so it docent really "know" about the types, it just inserts the names. All the work comes from `read_field<T: FromLTV>(&self) -> LTVResult<T>` amd all the primitives impliment the `FromLTV` interface. I could make the macro specifically look for `Option` fields but im looking for a solution that doesn't require patching in a specific case for a type because doing so would mean things like `struct MyFieldValue(Option<u8>)` or making type aliases `type OptionalData = Option<u8>` wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: This code is up on github currently, ive just decided to try and come fix up the performance issues.  Just to warn you, the macro code is not plesant.
Macro code: https://github.com/pigeonhands/ltv-rs/blob/master/ltv_derive/ltv_derive_impl/src/object.rs

How `Option` is currently handled: https://github.com/pigeonhands/ltv-rs/blob/be561118906aaf18a713f1ac93e75923d33129a3/ltv/src/object.rs#L115